# Running H2 embedded database in spring / hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am trying to create an spring boot application utilizing hibernate and h2. From what I have found online this can be done but I am having a problem starting the application. Hibernate is complaining that it cannot make a connection to the h2 database I have created.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:h2:~/todo]
```

My theory is that the application needs to start for the database be available but hibernate is not letting the application start without the connection.

Am I on the right track with this theory, has there been similar issues that someone knows how to get around this?

Hibernate config

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/todo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password" />

        <!--Set the database dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!--Echo all executed SQL to stdout-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!--Drop and re-create the database schema on startup-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!--Name the annotated Entity classes -->
        <mapping class="com.todo.beans.User" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>**
```

h2 config

```
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean( new WebServlet());
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change following properties in hibernate config

`<property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:todo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
</property>`

> Problem is with driver class; you may keep url as it is.

Comment: This worked! mind supplying a little background as to why this was the solution?

Comment: Actually DriverManager class of java.sql package uses connection.driver_class property.The DriverManager class acts as an interface between user and drivers. 
It keeps track of the drivers that are available and handles establishing a 
connection between a database and the appropriate driver. [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) loads this initial drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This sample project can help you.

https://github.com/dornala/HotelStackoverflow